# How to determine element position relative to the center of the parent

Tags: silverlight

I know that I can get the position of an element relataive to it's parent top and left with the following code:

```
var generalTransform = childElement.TransformToVisual( parentElement );
var childToParentCoordinates = generalTransform.Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
```

And I realize that if the child is left or above the parent the x and y will be negative.

However what I need is the point of the child's centre relative to the parent's centre, such the parent's centre is considered the (0,0) `point`.  So an object that is above and left of the center of it's parent would be a (negative, negative) `point` and to the right and below would obviously be a (positive, positive) `point`

Comment: Consider that all you need to do in order to translate from a TopLeft co-ordinate to a Center co-ordinate is to add Size/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Point relativePoint = child.TransformToAncestor(parent)
                      .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        Point parentCenter = new Point(parent.ActualWidth / 2, parent.ActualHeight / 2);
        Point childCenter = new Point(relativePoint.X + (child.ActualWidth / 2), relativePoint.Y + (child.ActualHeight / 2));
        //Now you can compare them as you want
```

I hope this will help.